# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 250, 1) vs (None,)). What is wrong?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new to ML and im trying to make a simple MLP work using serialization. I'll be using 2 layer MLP and binary outcome. (yes/no) Could someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Data is of following format. Basically trying to figure if a the address is gibberish or not.

```
(['10@¨260 :?Kings .]~H.wy ','3109 n drake' '(1`72¿0" |3¥4®th St SE'],['something else','something else 2'],[1,0])
```

Error received:

```
Error: ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 250, 1) vs (None,)).
```

Code:

```
def train_ngram_model(data,
                      learning_rate=0.002,
                      epochs=10,
                      batch_size=3000,
                      layers=2,
                      units=64,
                      dropout_rate=0.5,
                      num_classes=2,
                      vectorize=Vectorize()):
    encoder = vectorize.charVectorize_tfid(data[0])
    # encoder.adapt(data[1])
    # encoder.adapt(data[2])
    # encoder.adapt(data[3])
    # encoder.adapt(data[4])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(encoder)
    model.add(Embedding(
        input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim=64,
        # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
        mask_zero=True))
    model.add(Dense(units))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.45))
    model.add(Dense(units))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(data[1], data[5].astype(np.int), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the input dimensions, you see I am using the sequence-to-sequence input with simple vocabulary and I read from your model and code trying to predict that is the word sequence contains of those inputs or similarities

For only word contains you can use the input generators for the model but we see you need more than that with the prediction then we add the prediction methods.

****[ Sample ]:****

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
epochs = 50
learning_rate = 0.002
batch_size = 4
layers = 2
units = 64
dropout_rate = 0.5
num_classes = 2
input_vocab_size = 128
output_vocab_size = 64
embedding_size = 48
hidden_size = 32
max_time = 7
batch_size = 1
n_blocks = 7
n_sizes = 4

vocab = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ ])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def train_ngram_model(data, learning_rate=0.002, epochs=10, batch_size=32, layers=2, units=64, dropout_rate=0.5, num_classes=2, vocab=vocab):
    
    embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_vocab_size, embedding_size)
    ###
    decoder_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(hidden_size)
    sampler = tfa.seq2seq.TrainingSampler()
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_vocab_size)
    decoder = tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(decoder_cell, sampler, output_layer)
    
    ########################## 
    input_ids = tf.random.uniform(
    [n_blocks, n_sizes], maxval=input_vocab_size, dtype=tf.int64)
    
    layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
    input_ids = layer(data)
    ##########################    

    input_lengths = tf.fill([batch_size], max_time)
    input_tensors = embedding_layer(input_ids)
    initial_state = decoder_cell.get_initial_state(input_tensors)
    
    output, state, lengths = decoder( input_tensors, sequence_length=input_lengths, initial_state=initial_state )
    logits = output.rnn_output

    label = tf.constant( 0, shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.float32 )
    input_ids = tf.cast( input_ids, dtype=tf.float32 )
    input_ids = tf.constant( input_ids, shape=(1, 1, n_blocks, n_sizes), dtype=tf.float32 )
    
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( input_ids, input_ids ))
    
    
    return dataset

def model_initialize( n_blocks=7, n_sizes=4 ):

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(n_blocks, n_sizes)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])
            
    model.summary()
    
    model.compile( loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'] )
    
    return model

def target_prediction( data, model, n_blocks=7, n_sizes=4, input_vocab_size=128, vocab=vocab ):

    ########################## 
    input_ids = tf.random.uniform(
    [n_blocks, n_sizes], maxval=input_vocab_size, dtype=tf.int64)
    
    layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
    input_ids = layer(data)
    ##########################    

    prediction_input =  tf.cast( input_ids, dtype=tf.float32 )
    prediction_input = tf.constant( prediction_input, shape=( 1, n_blocks, n_sizes ), dtype=tf.float32 )
    predictions = model.predict( prediction_input )
    result = tf.math.argmax(predictions[0]).numpy()

    return result

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Working logicals
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
data = tf.constant([["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"], ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"], ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"], ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"]])
dataset = train_ngram_model( data, learning_rate, epochs, batch_size, layers, units, dropout_rate, num_classes )
model = model_initialize( n_blocks=7, n_sizes=4 )
model.fit( dataset, epochs=epochs, batch_size=1)

##########################
data = tf.constant([["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"], ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"], ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"], ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "z", "b"]])
result = target_prediction( data, model, n_blocks=7, n_sizes=4, input_vocab_size=128, vocab=vocab )
print( "result = " + str(result) )

input('...')
```

**[ Output ]:**

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqRNT.png)